# how to run wireless wifi adapter tl-wnb821N on virtualbox for ubuntu

Tags: networking

maybe it was there discussed before but i have never ever found a solution for this and iam trying it for long time, I was trying many ways but it always didnt work.the problem is that my wifi adapter tl-wnb821N  is not working,when i plug other devices like standart usb it works,when i plug wifi adapter it doesnt work even it wont change a adapters color.

Comment: You cannot run WiFi hardware on a Virtualbox guest. You must run the WiFi hardware on the Virtualbox Host, then edit your Virtualbox networking configuration to permit the Guest access to the network. Remember, Virtualbox only *pretends* to be hardware to the Guest.

Comment: @user535733 partially true. USB passtrough provides the USB device to the guest.